# ¿Estoy trabajando dentro de un SO montado en una máquina virtual?

Tags: linux, microsoft, virtualización, rhel

Tengo acceso vía SSH a un Linux. Ejecuto `cat /etc/os-release | grep "NAME"` para ver el nombre completo y versión de este Linux, y el comando me devuelve: **NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3"**.

De acuerdo, estoy trabajando en un RHEL.

Pero si ejecuto este otro comando `dmidecode -t system` me devuelve esto otro:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
        Product Name: Virtual Machine
        Version: Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.0
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: None
        Family: Virtual Machine
```

¿Linux y Microsoft listados en la información de mi sistema? ¿Qué exactamente significa esto?

Supongo que existe una máquina física en algún lado (con cables y ventiladores) que tiene un sistema operativo Microsoft, o sea un Windows. Y que en él se instaló un software como VirtualBox o VMWare con el fin de crear una máquina virtual donde se instaló un Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Al final de cuentas, yo tengo acceso a ese RHEL montado en esa máquina virtual. ¿Esta es la interpretación correcta de la información que recupero con dichos comandos?

Comment: Si, tu conclusión es correcta, estas en un host windows que ejecuta [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Supported_guests) para virtualizar otros sistemas. Hace unos 10 años en Windows usaban [VirtualPC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) para virtualizar, pero ha sido sustituido por Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, puede que estés trabajando en un servidor (por ejemplo de Microsoft Azure) corriendo una máquina virtual.

Mira esto: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V